# How to "mock" groups in molecule unit test for Ansible?

Tags: ansible, molecule

I have this task definition for a Role I have written a molecule unit test for.

```yaml
---
- name: Debug JDBC lines
  ansible.builtin.debug:
          msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ my_idx }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ item }}:3306/np"
  with_items: "{{ groups['db'] }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: my_idx
  when:
    - asp_srv is defined
    - anp_pkg_srv is defined
    - anp_pkg_srv in asp_srv
```

When I run `molecule test` I get this error:

```
TASK [bern.numberprovisioning : Debug JDBC lines] *********************
fatal: [centos7]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'db'"}
```

I was hoping for output close to this:

```
jdbc_connection_string_np0=jdbc:mysql://mockdb-host1:3306/np
jdbc_connection_string_np1=jdbc:mysql://mockdb-host2:3306/np
```

Here is the `provisioner` section.  I think I need to put something there, but whatever I do I cause errors.

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    host_vars:
      centos7:
        asp_srv: "all,figapiv2,nisioning,ocessor"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I did not need to change the `provisioner` section of my `molecule/default/molecule.yml` file.  I needed to set my `platforms` section to:

```
platforms:
  - name: centos7
    image: ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    command: "/usr/sbin/init"
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
  - name: mockdb1
    image: ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest
    groups:
      - db
  - name: mockdb2
    image: ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest
    groups:
      - db
```

The above does what I need, but it is kind of annoying that I have to specify the `image` for mockdb1 & mockdb2.

Answer (score 1):

The inventory molecule runs against is defined under the `platforms` key of the `molecule.yml` file.

Example taken from the [documentation](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#platforms)

```yaml
platforms:
  - name: instance-1
    groups:
      - group1
      - group2
    children:
      - child_group1
```

Make sure to put `gather_facts: false` in your `converge.yml` and `verify.yml` if you need ansible facts to be populated.

Comment: I believe your suggestion would put instance-1 in groups: group1, group2 and child_group1 which not quite what I need.